# How to set kendoTimePicker "min" and "max" so that it makes sense?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have two time pickers to let the user specify when he started and when he ended a job.

With the way it works by default, the widget latest hour is 23:45 considering intervals of 15min.

So the user will never be able to enter **START:16:00**, **END:00:00** or even **END:23:59**.

```
        $("#end").kendoTimePicker({
            value:fin,
            interval: "15",
            format: "HH:mm",
            min: "00:00",
            max:"23:59"
        });
```

Comment: `max` and `min` have to be JavaScript `Date`s.

Comment: Support for ISO midnight representations is not consistent across browsers. Not all of them accept T24:00. IE does but IIRC Chrome does not, so that kendo cannot easily conform to ISO standard in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in `max` and `min` definition that need to be JavaScript `Date`. So the definition should be:

```
$("#end").kendoTimePicker({
    value   : new Date(),
    interval: "15",
    format  : "HH:mm",
    min     : new Date(2013, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0),
    max     : new Date(2013, 6, 15, 23, 59, 59)
});
```

And you will see that in addition to 23:45, you will have 23:59 (the `max` value).